# How to draw opengl Cube in android.view.TextureView

Tags: android, view, opengl-es, custom-view, textureview

I have a Textured Cube component in opengl android. Which is rotatable on touch event and we can use this component as individual view. 
But i am facing an issue while i am trying to use multiple cube components in scroll view.

I know that andorid does not support different glsurface view component in scrollview.

I heard about TextureView which has included with api level 14, which is able to hold open gl view and work like andorid native view, But i amd not able to implement the same opengl cube component with TextuerView.

so i have few queries

1. Is it possible to draw opengl cube component on TextureView ? if possible how ?

2  second problem with opengl view it takes time to load first time(showing as black screen for 1 or 2 seconds).

3. Can we implement the cube component with orthographic 2d projection with android custom view class (without opengl).

Answer (score 1):

You can use OpenGL ES with a TextureView, just as you would a SurfaceView.  It would probably be best to have a single EGL context and just treat each TextureView as a different surface.  That will avoid the overhead of having multiple contexts and switching between them.

It would be much more efficient to have a single surface and handle the rendering and scrolling yourself, but that's more work.

Grafika has a number of examples.  The simplest is the "[TextureView GL activity](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/TextureViewGLActivity.java)", which is somewhat unpleasant to watch but demonstrates the basic concepts.

Comment: Thanks @fadden i get success with texture view to draw cube but my cube is not working well can you please help me to sort out the problem here https://github.com/A86S/CubeTextureView